# How to save the user email and name in database while signing in with google?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

**I am using google auth and i want to save user data in database...How can i get user details here and save it to database?**

```
Future<void> signUpWithGoogle(
    BuildContext context,
    bool mounted,
  ) async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) return;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
       FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .set({
        // 
      });
      if (mounted) return;
      InfoBox.show(context, InfoBox.success, "Signed In With Google");
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      if (mounted) return;
      InfoBox.show(context, InfoBox.success, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't get the password, there should be a authentication token and refresh token you can save

Comment: okay, I can not get the password, I just want to save the email, name, etc. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the code under your try block as below

```
try {
  final authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

  if (authResult.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(authResult.user!.uid)
            .set({
          "Name": authResult.user!.displayName,
          "Email": authResult.user!.email,
        });
      }

  if (mounted) return;
  InfoBox.show(context, InfoBox.success, "Signed In With Google");

 
} on Exception catch (e) {
  if (mounted) return;
  InfoBox.show(context, InfoBox.success, e.toString());
}
```

**Please accept the solution if it solves your problem**

Comment: What if a new user comes and signs in with google not email and pass, then how can I get this? Is this solution solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, but can't I get just name and email not pass, as I cannot get the password because it is Google's authority?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your try block, you have to get UserCredential which gives the User object data to be saved in the next line.

```
    try{
    UserCredential userCredential =
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    User user = userCredential.user; // User is updated version of FirebaseUser
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(/*Add Mapped User object*/);}
```

You can use `user` object to get all the necessary data.

Comment: Is this block of code applicable to sign_in_google(), not with email and pass?

Comment: The UserCredential gets the user from all of the FirebaseAuth methods either be signInwithCredentials, signInWithEmailAndPassword or signInAnonymously. Once you get the User object from userCredential.user, you can get the username, email etc but not password ofcourse.

Comment: When you define the dataType User, you will get the access at compile time to all the fields you can get from the User which just logged in.

Comment: Okay, I got your point. Thank you.